# What does exclamation mark in makefile commands do?

Tags: make

I am trying to understand the impact of exclamation (and read) in following commands in a Makefile in a codebases I work with.

```
check-format:
    ! gofmt -s -l . | read;
    ! go run golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports -l . | read;
```

These commands are run on Mac and other unix based systems.

A lot of the questions about exclamation mark in bash scripts mention they are for history expansion. But, in context of the above Makefile, it does not seem to make sense.

Would appreciate any help in understanding what the `!` and the piped `read` accomplish here. Thank you!

Comment: Typically, `!` in Linux tools breaks out to a shell. For example, in `vi` I can type `:4,7 ! tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'`, which will pass lines 4 - 7 to `tr` on stdin, and replace them in the edit with the stdout, thereby uppercasing those lines. As the text to the right of each of your `!` seems to be a shell command, I assume the line in your makefile is replaced by the output of the command, and then re-processed as makefile syntax.

Comment: Seems that the `!` may be deprecated or non-Linux. GNU/make has a Shell Function command and a `!=` operator that also return the output of an external command into the makefile itself. <www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function>

Comment: I think `!` and `|` have their normal shell pipeline meanings in this context . In particular, `man gofmt` says that `-s` tries to simplify the code, while `-l` seems to print the filename to stdout if the result is different; since `read` exits successfully if it reads something, `!` inverts that meaning so the rule succeeds if no file fails the `gofmt -s` test. I haven't looked at the second command but I suspect something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As steeldriver [surmises](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/660387/what-does-exclamation-mark-in-makefile-commands-do#comment1243823_660387), this isn’t a Make construct but a shell construct: piping to `read` provides a test for content, and negating it provides a test for emptiness.

```
! command | read
```

succeeds if `command` produces no output.

You can see this without Make:

```
! true | read; echo $?
! echo bar | read; echo $?
```